# Is there a way to QGis read an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY field?

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase

[image: SHAPE]

this is the type and name that Qgis displays for me when I connect with a oracle table,it is not displayed as a geo column, there is a setting I'm missing? Can Qgis Read this type of data?

Comment: SDE stands for Spatial Data Engine and it is how ESRI stores spatial data into databases. You can't read SDE geometries directly from database. Instead you must have a SDE driver in between. I have no own experience on this, but if QGIS is compliled with GDAL which is compliled with SDE then you should be able to see your data with QGIS.

Comment: I don't know much about qgis, but you can select the sde.st_geometry field as Well Known Binary using the sde.st_asbinary(shape) function.